# Permission denied from /boot

Tags: fedora, boot, grub2, tty, less

when I typed less /boot/grub2/grub.cfg in tty2 i get permission denied an I did su - password and that did not work I am in fedora 20 64 bit [image: what did I do wrong]

Comment: Could you please expand upon "that did not work" - did you receive the same permission denied error? Was your password not accepted? It's difficult to answer without the full details.

Comment: @aliceinpalth Christopher helped me I was not in root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You failed to change into the root user.

To view that file, you must have root privileges.

You get that by using `sudo`:

```
sudo less /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

assuming `sudo` has been set up and that you have permission to use it.  The password that `sudo` asks for is your unprivileged user's password, not the root password.

If `sudo` has not been set up, then change into root with

```
su -
```

This will also ask for a password, but in this case it's the root account's password.

Once you are root, you should configure your other user so that it can use `sudo`.  You do this using `visudo`. See the `sudo` and `visudo` (and `sudoers`) manuals.